# How to left join intermediate result table after filter ta(subquery)?

Tags: mysql, select

```
+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table   | Create Table                                                                                                                           |
+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| stuInfo | CREATE TABLE `stuInfo` (
  `stu_name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `stu_no` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


+----------+--------+
| stu_name | stu_no |
+----------+--------+
| Abcd     |      1 |
| Acmn     |      1 |
| Borne    |      1 |
| Bence    |      1 |
| Lucy     |      1 |
| Jone     |      2 |
| Lucy     |      2 |
| Lily     |      2 |
+----------+--------+
```

I want to get the number of (A*, 1), (B*, 1) as below

```
+----------+--------+
| A        | B      |
+----------+--------+
| 2        |      2 |
+----------+--------+
```

I consider of using left join.

```
select count(ta.stu_name) as A, count(tb.stu_name) as B 
from (
    select stu_name, stu_no 
    from stuInfo 
    where stu_no=1
) filtered_table 
left join filtered_table ta 
    on stu_name like 'A%' 
left join filtered_table tb 
    on stu_name like 'B%';
```

However this doesn't work.
What I want to know is how can I first base on  some condition (my example, the condition is 'stu_no=1'), and then use the filtered table to do left join.
 I think the get the filtered table first can improve the performance as there are multiple left join tables(same table).

The worked sql is as below:

```
select count(ta.stu_name) as A, count(tb.stu_name) as B 
from ( 
    select stu_name, stu_no 
    from stuInfo 
    where stu_no = 1 
      and stu_name like 'A%'
) ta left join (
    select stu_name, stu_no 
    from stuInfo 
    where stu_no = 1 
      and stu_name like 'B%'
) tb on 1=1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your problem, but judging from your sample data you can use a conditional count:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN stu_name like 'A%' then 1 end) AS A
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN stu_name like 'B%' then 1 end) AS B
FROM stuInfo
WHERE stu_no = 1;
```

`CASE WHEN stu_name like 'A%' then 1 end` evaluates to 1 if stu_name starts with A and null otherwise. COUNT counts all non-null expressions.

Comment: TKS.   This sql will first filter table by "WHERE stu_no = 1", then "count"?

Comment: Yes, WHERE is evaluated before COUNT. Do you want it the other way around (not sure what that would mean though)? How would the result be affected if (Adam, 2) is inserted?